# Python 3: best way to reuse the code in project, when need to expose both classic + asyncio interfaces to user

Tags: python, asynchronous, design-patterns, async-await, python-asyncio

The project is Python 3 library (package), implementing custom stream binary protocol. Think of pair of stream processing classes:

`MyEncodingWriter(dst_stream)` - translates Python objects to raw byte stream
`MyDecodingReader(src_stream)` - translates raw encoded bytes to messages or Python objects

I need to support both blocking sync streams and `asyncio StreamReader + StreamWriter`, (probably, with subclassing from them)

I understand I can't use `coroutines` as regular sync functions directly.

I think to mimic asyncio reader/writer API's (`read(), readexactly(),...`)
in my classes `MyEncodingWriter()` and `MyDecodingReader()`, so the only differences will be extra async/await keywords in asyncio version.

It's strange for me I will have two copies or repos with very similar code which I can't reuse.

For now I have only this idea... 
...try to generate dynamically sync code from async (by stripping async/wait keywords) with help of metaclass, maybe?

It there some better approach?

TYA for any suggestions or beautiful sampes/repos of a such dual implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the blocking version a subclass of the async version, and wrap the calls. Not tested, probably has syntax errors, but along these lines:

```
class MyBlockingEncodingReader(MyEncodingReader):
    def readexactly(self, n):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(super().readexactly(n))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it will work, however what is overhead expected?
I think each call's wrap will add some %....  do you have any estimations of such overhead?

Comment: It's not really possible or helpful to guess at a percentage overhead. It highly depends on many things (and the I/O itself almost certainly overwhelms all the other overhead). You can only answer that question by profiling. Write it simply, see where your performance problems are, and then optimize those. Trying to micro-optimize around single function calls just leads to confusing code for no actual benefit. (If this piece of code is called so frequently that this would be the bottleneck, you probably want to rewrite this piece in C anyway.)